# Sharing name logos made with copyrighted fonts

Tags: copyright

Is it legal to share name logos for free that I made using copyrighted fonts? Do I need to write which font I used?

Comment: What does the licence for the font say?

Comment: It says I can use it for personal and commercial purposes but cannot share the ttf file with others.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what the license for the font says.

The license for Windows fonts, for example, allows pretty much anything including commercial use. You can freely design and distribute a logo containing Comic Sans!

Answer (score 1):

[united-kingdom](/questions/tagged/united-kingdom)

As far as **copyright** goes, such acts are explicitly allowed in the United Kingdom.

> 54. (1) It is not an infringement of copyright in an artistic work consisting of the design of a typeface—
>     (a) to use the typeface in the ordinary course of typing, composing text, typesetting or printing,
>     (b) to possess an article for the purpose of such use, or
>     (c) to do anything in relation to material produced by such use;
>     and this is so notwithstanding that an article is used which is an infringing copy of the work.
>
> — [Copyright Designs & Patents Act 1998](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/48/section/54)

A licence cannot impose copyright restrictions on acts which are explicitly allowed in legislation. You are using a typeface (section 54(1)(a)) and distributing material produced (section 54(1)(c)).

The licence could regulate other acts.